# Sequel: how to identify which item in column a are associated with the most of a specific set of values in column b?

Tags: sql, count, subquery, max

Right now I've got two tables: project and projectworker.

project holds the name of the project and its project id
projectworker holds the project id and which worker id has worked on it.

A worker can work on more than one project and a project can have more than one worker (so a project id will be repeated multiple times if it has many workers associated with it, a row for each worker).

I need to find the project with the most workers who have worked on more than one project.

I found the workers who have worked on more than one project with this sub-query:

```
SELECT worker_id 
FROM projectworker 
GROUP BY worker_id 
HAVING COUNT(worker_id) >= 2
```

which returns three worker ids (1,3 and 12)

Now how do I search through the projectworker table to find which project has the most of those three workers work on it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can query the same table like this:

```
SELECT project_id, COUNT(worker_id)
FROM projectworker
WHERE worker_id IN 
    (SELECT worker_id 
    FROM projectworker 
    GROUP BY worker_id 
    HAVING COUNT(worker_id) >= 2)
GROUP BY project_id
ORDER BY COUNT(worker_id) DESC
```

Comment: This is gorgeous. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

So, first find the workers who have worked on more than one project:

```
select worker_id, count(*) as numprojects
from project_worker
group by worker_id
having count(*) > 1;
```

Then, use that for a filter on the projects:

```
select pw.*
from project_workers pw
where pw.worker_id in (select worker_id
                       from project_workers
                       group by worker_id
                       having count(*) > 1
                      )
```

Then you can add `group by` and order by the number of such workers:

```
select pw.project_id, count(*)
from project_workers pw
where pw.worker_id in (select worker_id
                       from project_workers
                       group by worker_id
                       having count(*) > 1
                      )
group by pw.project_id
order by count(*) desc;
```

This will give you the list of projects in order by that criteria.